# How to Parse XML Response of Http Post in Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, post, saxparser

I have an XML response from HTTP POST of this form

```
<PaymentResponse><TransDate>301111</TransDate><TransTime>011505</TransTime><SourceID>0</SourceID><Balance>0</Balance><ResponseCode>06</ResponseCode><ResponseMessage>Error XXXX</ResponseMessage><ApprovalCode>DECL</ApprovalCode><ApprovalAmount>0</ApprovalAmount></PaymentResponse>
```

But I am unable to parse it using Sax parser. Kindly help me out.
regards

I am using this code

```
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException  { 
    if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("TransDate"))
    {
        int tD = Integer.parseInt(currentValue); 
        tempResponse.setTDate(tD); 
    }
```

But every time localName comes with empty string.

Comment: Please be more specific why you could not parse this: do you get an exception somewhere? Do you need to know how to retrieve the data from the HTTP request? If so, what are you using to do the post request - an URLConnection, Apache's HttpClient, ...?

Comment: Why are you unable? What have you tried? What doesn't work?

Comment: The solution is to fix the bugs in your code. Make sure to fix them all.

Comment: Why are you unable to parse it with SAX? Do you need an introduction? Or are there any exceptions/problems?

Comment: I am using this code 'public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
   throws SAXException {
  if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("TransDate")){
   int tD = Integer.parseInt(currentValue);
   tempResponse.setTDate(tD);
  }'

Comment: But there is Null vale in 'localName' and it does not match with "TransDate".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As to your specific question: have a look at 'qName' argument instead: local name is only populated when parser uses namespace-aware mode. qName should contain "qualified" name, ie. concatenation of prefix (if any) and local name; so something like "ns:element" (if there is a prefix), or "element" (if no prefix).